# Teradata using Top 10 and Distinct

Tags: sql, teradata

I am getting an error saying that I cannot use Top 10 with distinct I am wondering if there is any way I can get my query to work on that fashion. this is what the error is saying .

[Teradata Database] [6916] TOP N Syntax error: Top N option is not supported with DISTINCT option.

Query Below:
Thank you.

```
 Select Distinct TOP 10   t1.Adjustment_ID, t1.OfficeNum, t1.InvoiceNum, t1.PatientNum,
t1.CurrentStatus, t1.AdjustmentTotal, t1.SubmittedOn, t1.UserSubmitted,
t1.Invoice_Type, t1.Pat_First_Name, t1.Pat_Last_Name,t2.Reason_Code FROM App_UnityAdj_AdjInfo_Tbl t1
Left Join RCM_WORK_PRD.App_UnityAdj_AdjRecord_Tbl t2 
On t1.Adjustment_ID = t2.Adjustment_ID
Where t1.UserSubmitted = 'Name' AND (t1.CurrentStatus = 'Pending' OR t1.CurrentStatus = 'Deny')
```

Comment: What are you trying to do? Can you show some example data and expected result? You can't use `GROUP BY` like this, Teradata is not mysql :)

Comment: I thought it was already stated Top 10 and Distinct. I am trying it with sample 10. I thought that was obvious enough. yeah I know about the group by I was trying different things.

Comment: You can't use both `TOP` and `DISTINCT` in a Select (because both are logically calculated at the same time) , but as Gordon showed you can do `TOP` and `GROUP BY`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What are you trying to do?  You have columns in the `SELECT` that are not in the `GROUP BY`.  You also have `TOP` without `ORDER BY`, which is suspicious.

One simple method is to move all the `SELECT` columns to the `GROUP BY`:

```
select TOP 10  t1.Adjustment_ID, t1.OfficeNum, t1.InvoiceNum, t1.PatientNum,
       t1.CurrentStatus, t1.AdjustmentTotal, t1.SubmittedOn, t1.UserSubmitted,
       t1.Invoice_Type, t1.Pat_First_Name, t1.Pat_Last_Name, t2.Reason_Code
from App_UnityAdj_AdjInfo_Tbl t1 Left Join  
     RCM_WORK_PRD.App_UnityAdj_AdjRecord_Tbl t2 
     On t1.Adjustment_ID = t2.Adjustment_ID
where t1.UserSubmitted = 'Name' AND
      t1.CurrentStatus in ('Pending', 'Deny')
group by t1.Adjustment_ID, t1.OfficeNum, t1.InvoiceNum, t1.PatientNum,
         t1.CurrentStatus, t1.AdjustmentTotal, t1.SubmittedOn, t1.UserSubmitted,
         t1.Invoice_Type, t1.Pat_First_Name, t1.Pat_Last_Name,t2.Reason_Code;
```

Comment: well I want to use distinct and top at the same time.

Comment: I literally just threw a sample query for testing I am not using group by because I am trying it with a generated query that Toad gave me.

Answer (score 1):

I think I figured it out, in case anyone wants to know it is sample 10

```
Select Distinct t1.Adjustment_ID, t1.OfficeNum, t1.InvoiceNum, t1.PatientNum,
t1.CurrentStatus, t1.AdjustmentTotal, t1.SubmittedOn, t1.UserSubmitted,
t1.Invoice_Type, t1.Pat_First_Name, t1.Pat_Last_Name,t2.Reason_Code FROM    App_UnityAdj_AdjInfo_Tbl t1
Left Join RCM_WORK_PRD.App_UnityAdj_AdjRecord_Tbl t2 
On t1.Adjustment_ID = t2.Adjustment_ID
Where t1.AssignedTo IS null AND (t1.CurrentStatus = 'Pending')
sample 10
```

Comment: Of course this might be a huge overhead, because the join and `distinct` is applied before the `SAMPLE`.  Depending on your actual data you might do a larger sample in a Derived Table to reduce the intermediate row count: `select top 10 ... from (select distinct ... from (select ... from ... sample 100) as a) as b`

Comment: So this is not the answer then ?

Comment: It *is* a correct answer, but for a large table it might be less performant compared to a nested `top ...( distinct .... (sample))` approach